# Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore

Tags: keytool, openjdk-11

I am adding a cert to the Java keystore and I get the following warning. The command is successful.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias my_root_ca.pem -file /usr/share/ca-certificates/foo/my_root_ca.pem
```

The warning is:

```
Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 52):

It's quite easy. If you check keytool manual you can see the following:

```
$ keytool -importcert -help
keytool -importcert [OPTION]...

Imports a certificate or a certificate chain

Options:

 ... removed for clearity
 -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
```

To get rid of that warning you must use -cacerts option instead of calling cacert keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias my_root_ca.pem -file /usr/share/ca-certificates/foo/my_root_ca.pem
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, feel free to accept it.

Comment: In the java 11, isn't possible to use `-keystore` and `-storetype` when is usign `-cacerts`

Comment: Like @PauloMateus said,  I'm using Java 11 and needed to remove the `-keystore` argument to use `-cacerts` --> `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -v -cacerts -storepass changeit`

Comment: Just a note as context: `-cacerts` option for `-importcert` was introduced in Java 9.

Comment: it's unclear to me *which* "the" cacerts store is accessed (managing a build server with multiple java JDKs: 8, 9, 11, 17).
Is it cacerts from system %JAVA_HOME%? or the cacerts from the current folder? or the cacerts in the same java-dir as the current keytool version? Even the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) is not helpful which is "*THE*" cacerts.
So, I kept using the `-keystore` option, despite the warning, to be certain.

Comment: The documentation says:<br/>

The cacerts Certificates File
A certificates file named cacerts resides in the security properties directory:

Oracle Solaris, Linux, and OS X:: JAVA_HOME /lib/security

Windows: java.home\lib\security

java.home is the runtime environment directory, which is the jre directory in the JDK or the top-level directory of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).'